# Popover works for IOS 7.1 but is empty for IOS 8.3

Tags: ios, ios8, uipopovercontroller, ios7.1, uipopover

I have a problem where my popover works correctly for IOS 7.1 but shows up empty for IOS 8.3.

```
    self.view.endEditing(true);
    let timeViewStoryboard : UIStoryboard?;
    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {
        //IF IPAD
        NSLog("PAD");
        timeViewStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardiPad", bundle: nil);
    }
    else {
        //IF IPHONE
        timeViewStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil);
    }

    let timePickerViewController : TimePickerViewController = timeViewStoryboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TimePickerViewController_ID") as! TimePickerViewController;
    if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == .Pad {
        //Delegating
        //timePickerViewController.delegate = self;
        if (self.view.window != nil) {
            timePickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
            let popover = UIPopoverController(contentViewController: timePickerViewController);
            timePickerViewController.parentPopover = popover;
            let height = self.view.frame.height;
            let width = self.view.frame.width;
            popover.presentPopoverFromRect(CGRectMake(width/2,  44, 1, 1), inView: self.view, permittedArrowDirections: UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, animated: true);
        }
    }
```

This is what I'm using to display the popover.

This is what it looks like on iOS 7.1:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1paQ.png

This is what it looks like on iOS 8.3:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjppC.png

Thank you for any and all help

EDIT 3: I've now discovered that it is definitely not my code. Nothing shows up in the case of a direct segue from a storyboard button either.

EDIT 2: I've also tried using a different method of creating the popover.

```
timePickerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover;
                timePickerViewController.preferredContentSize = timePickerViewController.view.frame.size;
                let popoverTimePickerViewController = timePickerViewController.popoverPresentationController;
                popoverTimePickerViewController?.permittedArrowDirections = .Any;
                popoverTimePickerViewController?.delegate = self;
                popoverTimePickerViewController?.sourceView = self.view;
                let height = self.view.frame.height;
                let width = self.view.frame.width;
                popoverTimePickerViewController?.sourceRect = CGRectMake(width - 93,  35, 1, 1);
                presentViewController(timePickerViewController, animated: true, completion: nil);
```

but this method doesn't work either.

However, I've discovered that the popover does not show up empty for a UITableViewController instead of a UIViewController. The cells for a UITableViewController show up.

EDIT: I've added some Images to better show my problem. If anyone needs anymore information in order to solve my problem please ask and I'll happily provide as much information as I can. Thanks!

Comment: What is the .parentPopover property on TimePickerViewController?

Comment: I utilize it to dismiss the popover later on by giving the view controller a reference to the popover it is in. The reason I'm doing so is because the newer methods of creating a popover only work for ios8 and not ios7. I've actually discovered something new and will be posting an edit.